# How to make an alert controller in mac using swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I am new to Swift, and I'm trying to make a score collected program for Mac OS X. I do know about Swift programming on iOS, but I don't know that much about OS X Swift. So I wrote a program for OS X. I almost finished it, but i want to know how to make alert controller in mac using swift. I know how to do it on iso but i don't know how to do it on OS X and also i want to know how to use .isEmpty in 
OS X.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet var Maths: NSTextField! = NSTextField()
@IBOutlet var Science: NSTextField! = NSTextField()
@IBOutlet var English: NSTextField! = NSTextField()
@IBOutlet var Religious: NSTextField! = NSTextField()
@IBOutlet var History: NSTextField! = NSTextField()
@IBOutlet var Geography: NSTextField! = NSTextField()
@IBOutlet var ICT: NSTextField! = NSTextField()
@IBOutlet var Computing: NSTextField! = NSTextField()

@IBOutlet var Total: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet var AVG: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet var StudentName: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet var StudentClass: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet var Report: NSTextField!






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.


    }
}

@IBAction func CountTotalnAVG(sender: NSButton) {

    var Mathsc = Maths.stringValue.toInt()
    var Sciencec = Science.stringValue.toInt()
    var Englishc = English.stringValue.toInt()
    var Religiousc = Religious.stringValue.toInt()
    var Historyc = History.stringValue.toInt()
    var Geographyc = Geography.stringValue.toInt()
    var ICTc = ICT.stringValue.toInt()
    var computingc = Computing.stringValue.toInt()

    /*
    var add = (Mathsc?.advancedBy(Sciencec!).advancedBy(Englishc!).advancedBy(Religiousc!).advancedBy(Historyc!).advancedBy(Geographyc!).advancedBy(ICTc!).advancedBy(computingc!))
    */

    var add: Int = (Mathsc! + Sciencec! + Englishc! + Religiousc! + Historyc! + Geographyc! + ICTc! + computingc!)

    if (Mathsc! == " ") {

    }
    else{
        Total.stringValue = "\(add)"

        var divide:Int = add/8

        AVG.stringValue = "\(divide)"
    }
}

@IBAction func GetReport(sender: NSButton) {

    var Mathsc = Maths.stringValue.toInt()
    var Sciencec = Science.stringValue.toInt()
    var Englishc = English.stringValue.toInt()
    var Religiousc = Religious.stringValue.toInt()
    var Historyc = History.stringValue.toInt()
    var Geographyc = Geography.stringValue.toInt()
    var ICTc = ICT.stringValue.toInt()
    var computingc = Computing.stringValue.toInt()

    func getGrade(score: Int) -> String {
        let result: String
        switch score {
        case 80...100 :
            result = "A"
        case 75..<80 :
            result = "B"
        case 60..<75 :
            result = "C"
        case 50..<60 :
            result = "D"
        case 40..<50 :
            result = "E"
        case 0..<40 :
            result = "F"
        default:
            result = "F"
        }
        return result
    }

    Report.stringValue = "Grades you got: \(getGrade(Mathsc!) ,(getGrade(Sciencec!)))"



}


}
```

Comment: depending on what you are looking at displaying check out `NSAlert` which was semi analogous to `UIAlertView`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no difference between iOS or macOS related to UIAlertController...

```
    let title = "Do you want to save the changes made to the document?".localized
    let description = "Your changes will be lost if you don’t save them.".localized
    
    let discard = "Don't Save".localized
    let save = "Save".localized
    let cancel = "Cancel".localized
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: description, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let discardAction = UIAlertAction(title: discard, style: .destructive) { _ in
        // don't save action here
    }
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: save, style: .default) { _ in
        // save action here
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancel, style: .cancel) { _ in }
    
    alert.addAction(discardAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(saveAction)

    yourViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `UIAlertController` doesn't exist for macOS targets.