# Swift showing use of Unresolved Identifier 'UIAlertController'

Tags: macos, swift

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var helloButton: NSButton!
    @IBAction func showAlert(sender: AnyObject) {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello!", message: "Hello, world!",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.helloButton.setTitle("Clicked", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
```

Comment: yes, on OS X there is no UIKit :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`UIAlertController` is an iOS class, contained in `UIKit`. But as you're doing a Mac app extending `NSViewController` and not importing `UIKit` (instead `Cocoa`), this class is not available to you.

So if you want to create an alert in your Mac app, see for example [How to make an alert controller in mac using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750294/how-to-make-an-alert-controller-in-mac-using-swift)

Comment: The linked solution is wrong. It is suggesting to use UIAlertController, which doesn't exist in Mac.

Answer (score 2):

On mac OS you use `NSAlert` instead of `UIAlertController`. A nice example of using `NSAlert` is given [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433631/1724059).

Answer (score 0):

In my case was removing import Foundation or moving import UIKit above Foundation.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation //Remove if needed
```